# Automate bazel shutdown

Tags: bazel, remote-server

I am building a large project on a remote machine using Bazel.  Clean build times are around 30 minutes.  Incremental builds (changing code in 1-2 files) typically take around 10-20 seconds.

The problem I have is that when I log out of my machine and log back in again after 1-2 days the build command takes around 10 minutes even though I have not modified any source code.

If I call `bazel shutdown` and then call `bazel build` again the "no-build" op takes around 5-10 seconds (i.e. much better than the other "no-build" op).

If I log out and log back in again immediately I can see there is still a Bazel process running in the background, which disappears when I call `bazel shutdown`.  I am guessing that when I do not shut Bazel down properly it gets killed in such a way that corrupts or deletes cached data.  The long "no-build" op then spends a long time reconstructing data that was previously stored in the Bazel cache.

Is there a way to automatically shut down the Bazel server when I am disconnected?  Preferably this should work both when (i) I call `exit` from the command-line to log out, (ii) I get automatically disconnected through some kind of timeout or interruption in network connectivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up your development environment so that you sessions do not automatically exit / get killed, e.g., using a tool like `screen` or `tmux`.  When you want to end a session call `bazel shutdown` prior to `exit`.  Not completely automated but the point is that you should be in control of when your sessions end.